# Validating an integer field on a form

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have this input box in a blazor server application which should be an integer field.
I want to do validation to be sure that the value entered is an integer

```
     <div class="mb-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-lg" id="numberofclasses" @bind-value="_myModel.NumberOfClasses">
     </div>
```

I can see a lot of code online doing something like this.

```
        public bool MyValidation()
        {
            bool result = true;
            int numberOfClasses = 0;
            
            if (int.TryParse(_myModel.NumberOfClasses.ToString(), out numberOfClasses))
            {
                //it is a valid integer => you could use the distance variable here
                
            }else
            {
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Is this a standard way of validating an integer field?

Comment: Blazor Validation is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0). In particular, look at `InputNumber`. Also, look at the `[Range]` attribute for range validation.

Comment: Have you tried using an <InputNumber /> field instead of a <input type="text" /> field?

Comment: I can try <inputNumber> but I don't want a range

Answer (score 0):

If you want a number, use the `InputNumber` control, or `<input type="number">`

Browsers, especially on phones, have their own ways of handling certain kinds of inputs, which are familiar to their users.  If you try to make a custom control using a text input, then those native controls will be bypassed, which will very likely lead to someone closing the page in disgust.